# Sending emails using keycloak rest API

Tags: keycloak, keycloak-services

I am able to trigger verification emails by configuring the SMTP server details.

However, is there any way in keycloak to send emails using Rest API or any other means? Tried searching for such an api but no luck.

Answer (score 5):

Check the Admin documentation, the endpoints for sending emails are available , for instance , the verification :

```
PUT /admin/realms/{realm}/users/{id}/send-verify-email
```

https://www.keycloak.org/docs-api/11.0/rest-api/index.html

Comment: I am aware of this endpoint to send verify emails. I want an endpoint using which I can send email with contents.

Comment: Then I'm not sure to understand your question, you want a "generic" endpoint to send email with custom content ? That's not really in the scope of Keycloak and should be handled in your own business logic.

Comment: If you want a generic email endpoint you should take a look to SendGrid (https://sendgrid.com) or similar services

Comment: You could use the SMTP server relay service in SendGrid or other email APIs, but it would be better if Keycloak could send a webhook instead of smtp so that we could could design a web service that would transform and format the message and then send with the email API.

Comment: How to do this in Java?